# Deleting an element by index in a multimap in C++

Tags: c++, multimap

I have a multimap where the keys are sorted in descending order. 
How do I efficiently remove the first element (index 0) from the multimap without having to essentially 'find' the first element.

```
multimap<int,char,std::greater<int>> mymap;

mymap.insert(pair<int,char>(20,'b'));
mymap.insert(pair<int,char>(20,'c'));
mymap.insert(pair<int,char>(15,'a'));
mymap.insert(pair<int,char>(10,'c'));
```

This is kind of the pop() from a sorted stack which removes the `pair <20,'b'>`

Comment: `mymap.erase(mymap.begin())`

Comment: sorry, I spoke too soon. Should've checked this! Thanks.